# Explode en javascript dado un patrón especifico

Tags: javascript, string, explode

Dado el siguiente string

```
var log = `added 20-11-19 10:02 - Lucho Jara : Un golpe de suerte espero despierto. Canción: Luis Jara - Un golpe de suerte
           added 21-12-20 11:52 - baby shark : Baby shark, doo doo doo doo doo doo`;;
```

El texto con el que quiero realizar el explode es: `added 20-11-19 10:02 - Lucho Jara :`

El problema está en que la fecha y hora `20-11-19 10:02` pueden variar pero van mantener el formato (`added **-**-** **:** -`).

El nombre del autor luego de la fecha mencionada arriba también puede variar (este igual en longitud) `- Lucho Jara :` pero los separadores `- :` siempre se van a mantener.

Ahora, si nos fijamos en la descripción que le sigue, nos damos cuenta que igual podrían contener los caracteres `- :` por lo cual un explode tradicional no nos servirá

¿Se pueden utilizar comodines?¿Alguna forma eficiente para realizar esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O con expesiones regulares:

```
    function miFuncion() {
      var str = "added 20-11-19 10:02 - Lucho Jara : Un golpe de suerte espero despierto. Canción: Luis Jara - Un golpe de suerte";
// Lo importante sigue
      var regex = /^added \d{1,2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2} - .+ :/;
// 
      var resulta = str.match(regex);
      alert(resulta);
    }
```

(Este ejemplo regrese "added 20-11-19 10:02 - Lucho Jara :")

Answer (score 0):

Podrias implementar el método split de js, algo como:

`const str = 'tu texto';`

`str.split("added").join(', ').split('-')`

y de ahi ir moviendo lo que se necesita separar